# How can I use CMake's AUTOMOC feature with a custom Qt package?

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm working on converting an existing project to CMake. I'd like to use CMake's built-in [AUTOMOC feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html), but since I can't use `find_package(Qt4)` (due to the custom location of the project's Qt4 binaries/libs/headers/etc.) it's not clear how to enable it. What's the magic sauce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a portable makefile snippet that triggers automoc:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC TRUE)
set(QT_VERSION_MAJOR 4)

find_program(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE qt_moc48 PATHS ${MY_BINARIES}) 
add_executable(Qt4::moc IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Qt4::moc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE})
```