# CMake CMAKE_AUTOMOC in cross compilation

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, cross-compiling

I've following issue. I'm tring to use native mechanism build in CMake for cross compilation. I prepared following toolchain.cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /tmp/filesystem)

set(tools /opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

and in target `CMakeList.txt` is use:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

I expect that when I use `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM` set to `NEVER` the CMake, according to documentation, will use moc from `HOST`:

> If set to NEVER, then the roots in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH will be
>   ignored and only the host system root will be used.

However it still try to use moc from `TARGET` arm image rootfs.

I try to refind the moc executable like in first answer from this post: [How to include a certain Qt installation using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511370/how-to-include-a-certain-qt-installation-using-cmake) but with no luck.

I also try to set the `QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE` variable to proper path from `HOST` rootfs instead of `TARGET` one but also with no luck there. I event think that this variable isn't use by CMake when `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` is set to `ON` since after forcing change this cached variable cmake still use moc from `TARGET` rootfs.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

**# EDIT 1**

I found that the automoc generates such file in build folder:

`CMakeFiles/*target_name*_automoc.dir/AutogenInfo.cmake`

And in my case such variable is set to wrong path:

`set(AM_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE "/tmp/filesystem/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc")`

should be:

`set(AM_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/moc")`

I set `AM_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE` to correct value in main `CMakeList.txt` but still after mentioned file is generated with wrong path from `TARGET` rootfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to this post: [How can I use CMake's AUTOMOC feature with a custom Qt package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570791/how-can-i-use-cmakes-automoc-feature-with-a-custom-qt-package). As I assumed the `QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE` isn't use directly by `AUTOMOC`.

Before first qt `find_package` following lines must be added:

```
set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/moc)
add_executable(Qt5::moc IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Qt5::moc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE})
```

The issue here was that not only the variable `QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE` has to be set to proper value but finally the automoc uses just `Qt5:moc` target which must be declared before any qt package will be included in `CMakeList.txt` file.

This same issue is with other qt tools so more generic option will be:

```
file(GLOB Qt_bin /usr/bin)
find_program(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE qt_moc moc PATHS ${Qt_bin})
add_executable(Qt5::moc IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Qt5::moc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE})
```